# CSS media queries for screen sizes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am currently trying to design a layout which will be compatible for multiple screen sizes.  The screen sizes I am designing for are listed below:

**Screen Sizes:**

1. 640x480
2. 800x600
3. 1024x768
4. 1280x1024 (and larger)

The thing that I'm having trouble with is creating the css3 media queries, so that my layout changes when the window's width gets to one of these widths.  Below is an example of the media queries I'm currently using, but it is not working for me, so I'm wondering if someone could help me fix it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 901px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify3.css">
```

I tried going with a new set of media queries, but they still aren't working for me.  Could someone please help explain what I'm dong wrong.  Several of you have already tried explaining, but I'm not getting it.  The new media queries are displayed below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 1280px)" href="css/devices/screen/layout-modify4.css">
```

Comment: Could use javascript instead?

Comment: @Titanium Media queries are not static.  Resizing your browser will restyle the elements depending on which conditions the browser now satisfies.

Comment: @JaPerk14 could you be more specific as to what isn't working?  You do understand that a device that's 640px wide will load all 4 of those style sheets, right? (Because all of these expressions are true: 640 <= 640, 640 <= 800, 640 <= 1024, 640 <= 1280)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more specific.  Say for example that the browser width is 640, then the styles from 800, 1024, and 1280 sized media queries shouldn't apply.  I think you might have solved my problem, cimmanon.  You can I change my new media queries, so that they work properly and change styles when the browser's width changes to a certain width.

Comment: This is the opposite of a "responsive" design and you're increasing your effort 4x, as you'll have four designs to maintain. You should have one "fluid responsive" design for all the content, and then use media queries only to address specific issues. For example, if there's not enough room for a sidebar, that's not a device-specific issue, that just means you don't want your content squeezed beyond a certain limit, and that limit shouldn't be dictated by a device, rather it should be dictated by the content. By default, HTML is device independent--you're going in a device dependent direction.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unless you have more style sheets than that, you've messed up your break points:

```
#1 (max-width: 700px)
#2 (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)
#3 (max-width: 901px)
```

The 3rd media query is probably meant to be `min-width: 901px`.  Right now, it overlaps #1 and #2, and only controls the page layout by itself when the screen is exactly 901px wide.

Edit for updated question:

```
(max-width: 640px)
(max-width: 800px)
(max-width: 1024px)
(max-width: 1280px)
```

Media queries aren't like catch or if/else statements.  If any of the conditions match, then it will apply all of the styles from each media query it matched.  If you only specify a `min-width` for all of your media queries, it's possible that some or all of the media queries are matched.  In your case, a device that's 640px wide matches all 4 of your media queries, so all for style sheets are loaded.  What you are most likely looking for is this:

```
(max-width: 640px)
(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px)
(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px)
(min-width: 1025px)
```

Now there's no overlap.  The styles will only apply if the device's width falls between the widths specified.

Comment: You should probably reflect that in your code in your response.  I just wrote-up an entire answer and then re-read what you posted and saw that you had answered it by switching that max to a min.

Comment: `#3 (max-width: 901px)` controles the page all the time because it is the last definition and overrides all declarations set before.

Comment: nice explanation :)

Answer (score 94):

Put it all in one document and use this:

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 - 5s ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) 
only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media
only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) 
only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /*** You've spent way too much on a phone ***/
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge ----------- */
@media only screen
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
and (min-resolution: 192dpi)and (max-width:640px) {
 /* Styles */
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

At this point, I would definitely consider using `em` values instead of pixels. For more information, check this post: https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/.

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with your suggestion, it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Your last query should be for `Edge 7`s not `Galaxy S7`s

Answer (score 4):

For all smartphones and large screens use this format of media query

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}



/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/**********
iPad 3
**********/

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```