# Correct padding or margin when using fixed top bar

Tags: html, css

My client wants the site to be responsive and have a fixed-top bar. This is the layout in full width.
[image]

But he also wants it to be responsive, so when I resize elements should adapt nicely. The body element has a 60px padding to the top, to compensate for the fixed top bar. But when I resize this is no longer enough. This is the same image with the browser window resized. Notice how the top bar overlaps the other elements.

[image]

I'm using bootstrap (navbar-fixed-top). Does anybody know how to fix this?

Regards.

Comment: your expected outcome ?

Comment: For the top bar not to overlap content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses media tags to target different screen sizes and adjust css accordingly.

have a look here.

[CSS media queries for screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

Use a percentage for your `padding-top` instead of `px`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing any code, but try to wrap the "other elements" with a div (if not already done) and give it a top margin of 60px.

Comment: That's what I have now =\ I'm using padding, but have already tried with margin-top.