# How can I make my website width fit fully on iphone 5?

Tags: html, css, iphone, width

I am working on a new site for my photography hobby. the ad is faspix.com I have got it to fit onto laptop/desktops how I would like but I am having an issue with making the width fit onto my iPhone when I load the page on iPhone the height is there fully but the width only shows about half from left to right then I have to scroll right to see the rest of the width... I have tried a bunch of different media queries but nothing has really solved the issue for example when I switched the site_content to max width 100 it just shrunk the container on the iPhone. Can someone help me get this width issue fixed on the iPhone? Thanks

CSS:

```
media (max-device-width: 1024px) { /*IPad portrait AND netbooks, AND anything with smaller screen*/ /*make the design flexible if possible */ /*Structure your code thinking about all devices that go below*/ } 

@media (max-device-width: 640px) { /*Iphone portrait and smaller*/ } 

media (max-device-width: 540px) { /*Smaller and smaller...*/ } 

media (max-device-width: 320px) { /*IPhone portrait and smaller. You can probably stop on 320px*/ }
```

Comment: If you could provide some code on what you tried, for example, what media queries you used, that would be a great help!

Comment: hi matt, i have tried these so far

Comment: media (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /*IPad portrait AND netbooks, AND anything with smaller screen*/
  /*make the design flexible if possible */
  /*Structure your code thinking about all devices that go below*/
}
@media (max-device-width: 640px) {
 /*Iphone portrait and smaller*/
}
media (max-device-width: 540px) {
 /*Smaller and smaller...*/
}
media (max-device-width: 320px) {
 /*IPhone portrait and smaller. You can probably stop on 320px*/
}

tried a cpl of others as well but thats what i currently have in mobile.css file my site content is 1260px wide & i would like to make it fit:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you have copied onto here, your media queries seem to be incorrect, here are some example queires, as answered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes) question...

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Obviously add the styles as per requirements, and change media query sizes as needed!

For future reference, [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) has a good article for you to read up on Media Queries. Another thing you need to consider will be browser compatibility, as IE8 and before doesn't support this, as stated [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)

Comment: hey matt so i deleted the old media queries and put the top three as you listed above for smart phones then in my html file i put this line 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen" and (min-width:320px) and (max-height: 568px) and (maximum-scale: 2)">
 now do i need to add anything to my style.css as my container is 1260px wide but its still not fitting. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Hi there, you should put the code I have given your main CSS file. No need for media queries in the HTML file.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code inside the header!

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Comment: hey i just added that but it just made it zoom more and show less:( lol should i delete the other meta line above?

Comment: You should never use `maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no`...it's provides a poor user experience.

Comment: user-scalable=no stopped flickering problem with my project ... I think its useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no Code, just a shot in the dark.
Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
```

to the head of your HTML.

Comment: this is what i currently have 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" and (min-device-width:320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (maximum-scale: 2)"> ill try that though in a sec:)

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us your HTML file, or at least the head of it ^^

Comment: `device-height` is not something that is usually found in media queries....definitely remove that.

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help so far as i said below to matt i added the 3 styles he suggested for iphone into my mobile.css

Comment: then now in my html file i have this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen" and (min-width:320px) and (max-height: 568px) and (maximum-scale: 2)">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
but im wondering do i need to change anything my style.css file as the site container is 1260px wide and im only seeing half on the iphone unless i scroll over

Comment: I just can write it again, pleas post your HTML file, so that we can see everything. You can try : <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:320px)"> <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" and (max-width:320px) and (max-width: 568px) and (maximum-scale: 2)">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- modernizr enables HTML5 elements and feature detects -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

Comment: it wont let me post fully here, i thought you might be able to see on the site view page source? i have tried all these sugestions all on the page here with no luck so far unfortunalty i just can seem to get the full width:( in my mobile css now i just have 
media handheld and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) and (maximum-scale:2); {
}

media handheld and
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2);

im not sure why this code is not working as my other site essentialzmusic.com it works fine with that but on that site the container is 960 wide and here my main and site content is 1260 px wid

Comment: I assume you want to achieve a responsive design, right? For one, I think "handheld" is ignored by iPhones so they will never interpret your mobile.css, if you use a stylsheet with the media querys Matt mentioned, you should be fine for every device. Or look at response frameworks, like Twitter Bootstrap, what they use as media querys.