# Shrink website to fit width of iPhone and iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

I am having the same issue as this: [How can I make my website width fit fully on iphone 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794483/how-can-i-make-my-website-width-fit-fully-on-iphone-5)

I have added my media queries and it sort of works on an iPhone but the iPad is cropped so only about 75% of the width can be seen. Can anyone see any errors with my coding which might cause the iPad to ignore the media queries?

I have this within the head

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

My CSS

```html
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}

 
#container1 {
 width:1100px;
 margin:auto;
 }

.image { 
 margin:auto;
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
```

My HTML

```html
<body bgcolor="#e6ebe4">

<div id="container1">
 
 <div class="image">
 <img src="images/background.png" width="1100px" height="784px" name="background"/>
 <h4>
 <a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a>
 <br />
 <a href="images.html">IMAGES</a>
 <br />
 <a href="howitworks.html">HOW IT WORKS</a>
 <br />
 <a href="pricing.html">PRICING & PRODUCTS</a>
 <br />
 <a href=" ">BLOG</a>
 <br />
 <a href=" ">PRESS</a>
 <br />
 <a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a>
 <br />
 <br />
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/9tu8hgATFP/"><img src="images/insta.png" width="50px" height="50px" name="dot"/></a>
 </h4>
 </div>
 
</div>


</body>
```

It just seems odd that iPhone tries to shrink the site, however iPad ignores the media query

Any help really appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `shrink-to-fit=no` to your `meta-tag` content property. This should fix this behavior.