# Center Align the navbar after screen size is reduced and on button pressed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I an new to HTML/CSS and I am creating a webpage with a responsive navigation bar on the top. The problem I am facing is that when the `navbar` is collapsed and the button is pressed, the `navbar-items` are aligning on the left side of the opened navigation menu. I want the items to be aligned to center on the menu. I searched so much on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) and [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com), but I couldn't get a solution to my problem.

Here is my HTML code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
  <title>
    My Personal Portfolio
  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>Vatsal Sura</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">MY PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT ME</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is an image of the webpage when it is first loaded on large screen:
[image: Webpage on large screen]

---

And here is another image when the browser is minimized and the navigation bar is collapsed:
[image: With Collapsed nav-bar]

---

And when the button is clicked, the navbar is opened below the original one and the items are aligned to the left-side, but I want them to be aligned to center of the navigation bar.
[image: Left-aligned nav-bar]

---

**P.S.**: Here I want the `nav-items` to be right aligned at first when it is not collapsed, but I want them to be center aligned when they are collapsed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: From your code I see all you need is to text-align: center; in the media query. What doesn't work?

Comment: Check what class gets applied to the collapsed items and set `text-align : center;` for the additional class that gets applied

Comment: @MadalinaTaina How can I achieve that? I am really new to that, so I don't know what to do. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: @VatsalSura https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try adding the following CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in ul{ 
  text-align: center;
}
```

The `.in` class is added by bootstrap, when un-collapsing the navigation. Also, please make sure, that `li` are displayed `inline` or `inline-block`.

EDIT 1: 
I guess, its because, of the `navbar-right` class in `ul`

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in ul.nav{ 
  text-align: center !important; // Try to remove the important part.
}
```

Can you also, check developer tools to check if the classes are correct and the style is being overiden or not?

Edit 2:

Add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in ul{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-pills>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can you do a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But is it possible that the transition doesn't happen when we click on the button. As it is showing first on left side then coming to the center.

Comment: I figured that out and updated your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your website completely responsive, then you should write different css rules for different screen sizes...

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}


/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Refer to this question for more information : [CSS media queries for screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes)