# Youtube Iframe in Div with background stuck on image responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

---

Heey there,

I am trying to figure out how I can position the youtube Iframe in the right part on the background so it looks like youtube is being played from a laptop.
And then have it scale down accordingly with the background-image on different resolutions.

The website runs on width 100% the html code is

```
    <div class=youtube>
    <div class=youtubesmaller>
     <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?             list=PLJdPTgbeDGN08yHg1Y46vzwDhj5Nxb-y_" 
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And the css from the moment I noticed it wasn't scaling with the background is.

```
 /*music page stuf*/

 .youtube {
     background-image: url(http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/macbookframe.png?id=353) !important;
     background-size: auto;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     height: 600px;
 }
 .youtubesmaller {
     width: 51.2%;
     margin-left: 37.4%;
 }
 /*end music page stuff*/
```

In the beginning I tried to give the Iframe a background but then read that wasn't possible.

[website page](http://breakline.nl/music)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't provide you full solution for this but i hope i could help you anyway.

Change code like this:

```
.youtubesmaller {
margin-top: 63px;
width: 713px;
height: 446px;
margin-left: 161px;
}

.youtube {
background-image: url(http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/macbookframe.png?id=353) !important;
background-size: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
height: 600px;
width: 1034px;
float: right;
}
```

In youtube iframe change height to 100% (style="height: 100%;").

If you want to scale it - look on CSS for screen resolution - [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes)

Let me know in comment if i helped you :)

Comment: Hello thanks alot for the response!
Following your instructions I got the player in the screen but it wasn't high enough.
iframe displays width: 100% and height:100px in browser.
Iframe is not as big as the inner wrap.
The only number that is changing whilst resizing the window is the height in this code.
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="height: 401.062px;"></iframe>
I see that this is element style and when I edit it to 450 the image is correct.
after resizing its back to the old.

Comment: Did you add [ style="height: 100%;" ] to iframe? Like this:

<iframe width="100%" height="100%" style="height: 100%;" src="linkhere" 
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Yes I have exactly that

Comment: I tried the solution below edited for this code. I added .youtubesmaller iframe { width: 100% !Important; height: 100% !Important; }  And it worked! What solution is better for future responsiveness?

Comment: Your solution is good. Now you need to add responsiveness via CSS for screen resolution.

Comment: Will definitely do, your help was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it to work as you requested.

First I added the set height and width to your iframe:

```
<iframe width="714px" height="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLJdPTgbeDGN08yHg1Y46vzwDhj5Nxb-y_" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style=""></iframe>
```

Then set the width on your wrapper in pixels (this result will not be responsive, but I noticed you don't have a responsive page). Also I added float right and position relative:

```
.youtube {
    background-image: url(http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/macbookframe.png?id=353) !important;
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 600px;
    ***width: 1039px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;***
}
```

Then I positioned the inner div absolutely in the appropriate spot:

```
.youtubesmaller {
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    left: 165px;
}
```

I did this right on your site in the browser inspector and here is the screenshot of the result: http://screencast.com/t/hgJkgbQktF

Comment: Hi there thanks for your response! 
I tried this out and got the player in the top left corner of the screen filling about 1/4th of the screen. 
I went to check why it wasn't bigger and I noticed that the Iframe's code properties were not the same as in browser. 
Browser still displays width: 100% 
Width can't be adjusted, it resets to 100% on the page eventhough my code says something else.
Also I changed it in the browser but it didn't do anything.
I tried the other answer
And discovered that changing the iframes width and height doesn't do anyhting visual on my screen.

Comment: You can try forcing the width and height of the iframe .youtubesmaller iframe {
    width: 714px !Important;
    height: 450px !Important;
}

Comment: That worked! And it helped me fixing the code from the other answer aswell. I don't know which code to use. Would the other answer be better for future responsiveness?