# How to show images in mobile devices instead of a video background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get mobile devices to display an image instead of a video background. This is what I have got so far, but it doesn't work. It is still displaying video on all devices, I have tried adding the image as a background but that did not work.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/8t17jLy0/2/

The js file with the code for the video is here:

https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/jquery.vidbacking.js

Video CSS:

https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/jquery.vidbacking.css

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>

        <!-- ALL CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/owl.theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/flaticon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/settings.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/style.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/preset.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/css/responsive.css">


    </head>
    <body>

        <!--BANNER VIDEO BG START-->
          <section >
            <div class="cid-qTkA127IK8 mbr-fullscreen">
                <!--<iframe width="100%" height="100vh" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dfokqepD5NY?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen  class="cid-qTkA127IK8 vidbacking mbr-fullscreen"></iframe>-->
                <video poster="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/images/bg/bg-home-mobile.jpg" autoplay muted class="cid-qTkA127IK8 vidbacking mbr-fullscreen" media="(min-width: 990px)">
                    <source src="" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/videos/hero.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1030px)" srcset="images/bg/bg-home-mobile.jpg">
                    <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/images/bg/bg-home-mobile.jpg">
                    <img class="mobile-image" src="images/Goodstuff-Office-Mobile-Header.jpg" alt="" />
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: 0.4; background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"></div>
            <div class="mouseSlider">
                <a href="#ourwork" class="normal"><img src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/images/mouse.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#ourwork" class="hover"><img src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/images/mouseh.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>

        </section>

        <!-- ALL JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/slick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/theme.js"></script>
        <script src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/js/jquery.vidbacking.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('body').vidbacking({
                    'masked': true
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: using CSS you could hide the video on small screens, check out this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes#13847835

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your on mobile with this:

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
    isMobile = true;
}
```

Then maby something like:

```
if (isMobile) {
   $("body > section cid-qTkA127IK8").append('
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1030px)" srcset="images/bg/bg-home-mobile.jpg">
                    <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/images/bg/bg-home-mobile.jpg">
                    <img class="mobile-image" src="images/Goodstuff-Office-Mobile-Header.jpg" alt="" />
                </picture>');
} else {
   $("body > section cid-qTkA127IK8").append('
                <video poster="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/images/bg/bg-home-mobile.jpg" autoplay muted class="cid-qTkA127IK8 vidbacking mbr-fullscreen" media="(min-width: 990px)">
                    <source src="" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="https://pruebasvirality.000webhostapp.com/videos/hero.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>');
}
```

I hope this is what your looking for! Otherwise please let me know!