# How can I code a clickable icon to resize with window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a personal project to replace shortcuts in google sites with coded short cuts. I'm doing so to give the shortcuts a shadow box effect when hovering over them. Unfortunately, when the website is ran in smaller screens or resolutions, the shortcuts are not resized. I'm seeking guidance on how to implement this without ruining the current code I have set.

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change Image on Hover in CSS</title>
<a href="https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/signin/c0bfa137-8b9d-4932-b679-7691f7e554a7?tenantId=7943f8c0-cf11-411f-800f-3c985acdf6ec" target="_blank">
<style>
    .card {
        transition: box-shadow .3s;
        width: 155px;
        height: 48px;
        margin: 1px;
        border-radius:1px;
        float: left;
        background: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1XlH5BS7Geh_1mjDwQo4FQOsxcmxa5OWG") no-repeat;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        background-position: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); 
        width: 155px;
        height: 48px;
        
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</a>
</body>
</a
```

I've tried resizing the image in the shortcut, reducing margins and padding to 0. I'm self learning HTML and CSS so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Look into the CSS [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) and [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) properties along with setting the image size to a relative unit.

Comment: I would recommend looking into media queries and responsive design. Also your code is broken, you have a random anchor sitting in your head, but then it is ended within the body and after the body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS media queries for screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847755/css-media-queries-for-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

It is so good that you learn through practice. Continue.
I modified a little bit your code like this:

```css
.card {
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
    width: 155px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius:1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); 
    width: 155px;
    height: 48px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color:blue;
    }
    .card{
        width: 105px;
        height: 30px; 
    }
    img{
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px; 
    }
    .card:hover{
        width: 105px;
        height: 30px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change Image on Hover in CSS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/signin/c0bfa137-8b9d-4932-b679-7691f7e554a7?tenantId=7943f8c0-cf11-411f-800f-3c985acdf6ec" target="_blank">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1XlH5BS7Geh_1mjDwQo4FQOsxcmxa5OWG">
        </div>
    </a>
</body>
```

1. If you want to resize your screen you can use [Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). This will change the background color to blue (I added it for example) and size of your button for screens that are 600 pixels wide or smaller. This is especially useful for styling mobile or smaller tablet views of websites, as it allows you to optimize the layout and appearance for smaller screens.
   In a typical responsive design, you'd often see multiple media queries targeting different ranges of screen sizes, enabling the webpage to adapt its layout and design across various devices, from smartphones to large desktop monitors.
2. It is better to separate files .html, .css and .js for many reasons. For example

- maintainability: By separating concerns, each file can focus on a single aspect of your web page: structure (HTML), presentation (CSS), or behavior (JavaScript). This makes it easier to find and fix issues or make updates. If everything is combined, it can become cumbersome to sift through code.
- reusability: CSS and JS files can be reused across multiple HTML pages. This means you can maintain a consistent look, feel, and behavior across different parts of a website without duplicating code.
- flexibility with Loading Scripts: When scripts are in external files, you have more flexibility in terms of where and how they are loaded. For instance, you might choose to defer loading of some non-critical JS files to improve initial page load times.
- SEO (Search Engine Optimization): Some believe that keeping scripts and styles external can be beneficial for SEO. Search engines prioritize content, and by minimizing inline styles and scripts, the actual content can be parsed faster.

3. float is deprecated it is better to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to place all elements on the page.
   [flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) helps to learn it.